# PHP Array custom fusion of values

Tags: php, arrays, count

Good morning!
I'm using a SQL query to get category IDs from posts. Several post can have the same ID if they are from the same category. This is my array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [catid] => 48 )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [catid] => 77 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [catid] => 57 )
[3] => stdClass Object ( [catid] => 57 )
[4] => stdClass Object ( [catid] => 38 ))
```

Now I need to get the sum of all different catid's (in this case 4). I could achieve this by using "distinct" or a "group by" in my SQL, anyway I didnt because they mess up my results.

The problem is, that some catids should be replaced. For example is catid 48 'HDDs' and 77 is 'Storage' so 48 should be a part of 77 (So the sum is now 3). I already got an array of the catids that should be merged:

```
$catMergeArray = array(
38=>74,36=>46,34=>72,37=>73,40=>76,39=>75,103=>85,102=>81,53=>82,51=>80,50=>79,
55=>90,56=>91,57=>92,58=>93,55=>90,104=>68,106=>69,65=>70,66=>86,108=>95,48=>77,
172=>171,105=>170,111=>169);
```

by using

```
foreach ($result as $cats) {
 $newarray[] = $cats->catid;
}
```

I changed my Array to

```
$newarray = Array ([0] => 48 [1] => 77 [2] => 57 [3] => 57 [4] => 38)
```

Then (like mentioned in $catMergeArray where it says **48=>77**) remove the `[0] => 48` value so the result should be `$catids = Array ([0] => 77 [1] => 57 [2] => 38)` so I can count the elements and have **3** as result to work with.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how to replace the elements in my array as mentioned in `$catMergeArray`

Comment: Sorry but i think it would be easier to sort this data using SQL. Doing this is like manual process, arrays wont know what exact values should be removed.


Other solution - comparing device1 and device2 array category and removing the duplicate.

Comment: But in SQL I again have the problem that I need to say that some ids should be treaten as other IDs like in **$catMergeArray**

Comment: maybe i can help you with sql queries ;) you know how to use join?

Comment: yeah a bit. But with my SQL query I have some problems since they mess up my result somehow. I did open another question for that 2 days ago^^ Hmmm... this is not cool :( I thought it would be "easy" to replace values in an array when I got the array and an other array in which is declared what should be replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I now solved my problem with this:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $intArray[] = $value->catid;
} 
$uniqueArray = array_unique($intArray);
$cUniqueArray = count($uniqueArray);    

$cma = array(48=>77);

$lenght = $cUniqueArray-1;
for($i = 0; $i <= $lenght; $i++){
    $key = array_search($uniqueArray[$i],$cma);     
    if(is_int($key)){
        $uniqueArray[$i] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be better to do it in php. Here's a rough idea and some *pseudocode*.
probably not very efficent nor elegent, but it should work.

```
$list_of_id = mysqli_fetch_array(query("distinct catId"));
for($i=0;$i<count($list_of_id);$i++){
  $parent_cat_id = $catMergeArray[$list_od_id[$i]];
  if ($parent_cat_id > 0){
    for($j=0;$j<count($list_of_id);$j++){
      if($list_of_id[$j]==$parent_cat_id){
        unset($list_of_id[$i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
echo count($list_of_id);
```

EDIT: since OP doesn't seems to understand pseudocode...I'll make a php version... Surely it's clear enough?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding english is not my first language. I want to make it in PHP!

Comment: i didn't misunderstand, it was some fake code just to demostrate my concept. I was expecting you to understand my code and then let yourself write your own.

Answer (score 0):

ummm have you tried using array_unique? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

or you can also group them into a unique array index like this:

```
$summary = array();

foreach( $catids as $catid => $cat){

$summary[$catid][] = $cat;

}
```

Comment: array_unique wont help, since I try to remove/fuse different values! For example: When I have 3x elements with ID 77 and 2x Elements with ID 48, I want to remove or fuse those elements with id 77 (that coult be achieved by array_unique thats right) BUT afterwards I want to remove/fuse those elements with ID 48 together with the 77 IDs so there is only 1 element left. I just need the number of different elements AFTER this fusion/removal

Comment: let's say you have this array
`$catids = array(
['device1'] => 'cat1',
['device1'] => 'cat2',
['device2'] => 'cat1',
['device1'] => 'cat3',
['device3'] => 'cat1',
['device2'] => 'cat2',
)`

applying the loop above you will have this result 


`array(
'device1' => array(
'cat1','cat2','cat3'
),
'device2' => array(
'cat1','cat2'
),
'device3' => array(
'cat1'
),
)`

then you can use array_unique

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You thought of it more complicated than it is. When I post it like your example the array would look like `$catids = array(['device'] => 'cat1', ['device'] => 'cat2', ['device'] => 'cat1', ['device'] => 'cat3')` and I now need to remove duplicate entries (yes I know how to do with array_unique) **AND** replace all **cat3** elements because I said that both are the same main category. After this removal I need the number of all elements.

Comment: can you post the array / data structure  result that you want to achieve?